# javascript change body ID (with css) dynamically with respect to browser window size

Tags: javascript, css, window, size

Here is what I have, but it is not working:

```
 if(window.width() < 1000)
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].id="be"
else
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].id="bd"
;
```

Please tell me what I am writing wrong. Please don't tell other solutions, please just fix this code.

Basically, I want to give a different ID to the BODY tag of a website if the browser window size is less than 1000px.

Comment: Why a different ID? Why not just give it a class? Also, are you getting errors? How do you know it's not working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go:

```
document.body.id = window.innerWidth < 1000 ? 'be' : 'bd';
```

---

Place this code at the bottom of your page:

```
<script>
    function setBodyId() {
        document.body.id = window.innerWidth < 1000 ? 'be' : 'bd';
    }           
    window.onload = setBodyId;
    window.onresize = setBodyId;
</script>
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/THqXB/

Comment: @aaa You want to execute this on page load?

Comment: I want it to execute as thus:  when user makes browser window smaller, if they make the browser window smaller than 1000px, then I want to define ID of "be"

Comment: Also, I included this in my javascript file instead of on my index page. I just removed the <script> and </script>

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript but the optimal solution is to use CSS Media Queries for such scenarios.

see > [CSS Media Queries as Browser Resizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187390/css-media-queries-as-browser-resizes)

Comment: please tell more. However, if anyone has a solution to the above code, please tell me because the purpose is also to get better at writing javascript.

Answer (score 0):

`window.width()` is not a function. Use `window.innerWidth` or `window.outerWidth` instead. (check browser compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using jQuery, a JavaScript library. It handles a lot of browser incompatibility. For example, `innerWidth` and `outerWidth` properties are not supported in IE.

This will work cross browser:

```
$(function(){
    $("body").attr("id", $(window).width() < 1000 ? "be" : "bd");
});
```

If you want it to change as the window resizes, you need to add an event listener to the window resize event:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $("body").attr("id", $(this).width() < 1000 ? "be" : "bd");
});
```

Comment: this also looks great. where should I add this? Javascript file? Index main page file (it is index.php)? And how specifically? For example, what exactly should I copy into my Javascript file at the bottom? Thank you in advance!

Comment: okay, i just added that code to the bottom. However, it adjusted my entire page. Whereas if I just define the ID of "be" manually in the index.php file, it works for the smaller window and does not mess up my page.

Comment: @aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa11111111111111, you should be able to copy the two code snippets verbatim and put them wherever you want. I would recommend putting them in a JavaScript file to keep JS code separate from HTML.

Comment: Nevermind, my bad! I accidentally removed the closing } in the css file (whoops!). but this one is still not working for some reason...

Comment: okay, so I have solved this. However, if possible I would like to use your solution, because it will allow it to work on IE also.

Comment: This is what I used, which worked:

    function bodyID() {
        document.body.id = window.innerWidth < 1000 ? 'be' : 'bd';
    }           
    window.onload = bodyID;
    window.onresize = bodyID;
 
Now, can you please tell me how to use yours, so that it will be compatible with IE also, given the above code works?

Comment: @techuser7777777, apologies for the late reply. Just place this in your JavaScript file and in the `head` of your php file put a reference to it (e.g. `<script type="text/javascript" src="LINK_TO_YOUR_FILE.js"></script>`).

Comment: @techuser7777777, couple questions. Do you also include a link to jQuery? Is the `src` path to the file correct?

Comment: yes, I actually included it in another javascript file (the same one which I am using for the code which DOES work). The location is not the problem. The code is the problem.

Comment: @techuser7777777, I'm not sure what the problem is then. Are you getting any JavaScript errors logged? Here is a demo of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/wpXna/

Comment: me neither. ill just keep the working solution, and *(@#&!* IE! lol