# Applying different stylesheets for differently sized browser windows on the fly

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using the following code to select a different stylesheet if the browser is above or below a certain height. Works great when you land on the page, or if you resize the window then refresh. But is there any way I can tweak this to select the correct style sheet on the fly, as the window is resized?

```
if (window.innerHeight <= 900) {
    loadcss('css/container_sm.css');
} else {
    loadcss('css/container_lg.css');
}

function loadcss(file) {
    var el = document.createElement('link');
    el.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    el.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    el.setAttribute('href', file);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(el);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Media Queries as Browser Resizes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187390/css-media-queries-as-browser-resizes)

Comment: @Quentin I don't see how this is a duplicate. The link you have mentioned uses CSS3 media queries while the OP doesn't necessarily want to use CSS3 media queries. The link you have mentioned is good for further reading, but it doesn't deal with the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it could be worth looking into an existing library such as [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)? They offer responsive stylesheets out of the box that adjust automatically when the window is resized.

Answer (score 0):

You can add event handle to you script. With jquery

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   if (window.innerHeight <= 900) {
    loadcss('css/container_sm.css');
   } else {
    loadcss('css/container_lg.css');
   }

})
```

without jquery
window.onresize = function(){}

Comment: This is very inefficient. It will invoke the `loadcss()` on every resize of the browser. So if the user is resizing by dragging the edges of the browser, the `loadcss()` function would be called on every mouse movement. Also, it doesn't replace the existing LINK element. Instead, it keeps appending the new LINK element on every resize. If the user has resized the browser by dragging it from a height of 1000px to height of 200px, you would end up with 801 <LINK> elements appended to the <HEAD> element, and it would just keep growing with every resize.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we have to do:

1. Whenever the browser is resized, check that the resize has caused the browser height to change from small (<= 900px) to big (> 900px), or vice versa. If this hasn't happened, for example if the user has resized only from 600px to 601px, we don't need to replace the CSS.
2. Whenever, we detect that the browser has resized from small to big, or vice versa, we carefully select the old `container_lg.css` or `container_sm.css` and remove it.
3. Then, we add the appropriate CSS.

Here is the code:

```
var SMALL = 0;
var BIG = 1;
var previousSize = null;
var thresholdHeight = 400;
var firstCall = true;;

function selectCSS()
{
    if ((previousSize == null || previousSize == BIG) &&
         window.innerHeight <= thresholdHeight) {

        removeOldCSS();
        loadNewCSS('css/container_sm.css');
        previousSize = SMALL;

    } else if ((previousSize == null || previousSize == SMALL) &&
                window.innerHeight > thresholdHeight) {

        removeOldCSS();
        loadNewCSS('css/container_lg.css');
        previousSize = BIG;
    }
}

function removeOldCSS(file)
{
    var headNode = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var linkNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
    for (var i = 0; i < linkNodes.length; i++) {
        var linkNode = linkNodes[i];
        if (linkNode.parentNode == headNode &&
            linkNode.href.search(/css\/container_(?:sm|lg).css$/) >= 0) {

            headNode.removeChild(linkNode);
        }
    }
}

function loadNewCSS(file)
{
    var el = document.createElement('link');
    el.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    el.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    el.setAttribute('href', file);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(el);
}

window.onload = selectCSS;
window.onresize = selectCSS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.body.onresize = function (){
    if (window.innerHeight <= 900) {
        loadcss('css/container_sm.css');
    } else {
        loadcss('css/container_lg.css');
    }
};
```

Comment: This is very efficient for the same reason I have mentioned in a comment to Trinh Hoang Nhu's solution on this page.